# Azimuthal Quantum Number

Tags: quantum-chemistry, hydrogen

In the radial equation of hydrogen atom the differential equation is described by
[image]

But why is l taken to be integer. I know the principal quantum number n correspond to energy levels so that's why it's taken as integer. Why should azimuthal quantum number be taken as integer though

Comment: Do you know what $l$ is and whether number $1$ is an integer?

Comment: l is the angular momentum

Comment: But why is it an integer always when solving for hydrogen we use laguerre polynomials and solve the radial equation but then we substitute l as an integer in l(l+1)

Comment: When $\ell$ is not an integer, you'll get bad solutions.

Comment: Please [don't cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068) [your question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/590337/why-is-the-azimuthal-quantum-number-a-positive-integer). Instead, I'd suggest to grasp a more complete understanding on what $l$ is (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_quantum_number)). The short answer would be to look at the title: the word "*quantum*" kind of implies an integer.

Comment: @andselisk yeah I get that intuitively but I need a rigorous math explanation

Comment: @IvanNeretin what do you mean by bad solutions like can you elaborate

Comment: How rigorous an answer do you want? Your explanation for $n$ being integral, although correct, doesn't exactly sound very rigorous either. There is a lot of maths behind that. It falls out of the Schrodinger equation, much like how the condition for $\ell$ does, too.

Comment: If you want the maths, though, I honestly suggest checking out a QM book. There are lots of great ones out there. I'm sure many of them have the same derivation that show how $n, \ell, m$ have the conditions they do.

Comment: can you suggest which QM book has it

Comment: In pretty much any QM curriculum, harmonic oscillator predates the hydrogen atom. It is **then** that you've first encountered some number ($n$) which miraculously ends up being an integer. It is **then** that you should have asked yourself why is it so. The reason is the same: for non-integer $n$ you'll get bad (unphysical) solutions.

Comment: @zeeman $\ell$ Is NOT an angular momentum, it is just the integer quantum number determining the discrete values of orbital angular momentum.

Comment: @IvanNeretin when azimuthal quantym number is not an integer what bad solution do I get( like are the eigenvalues unreal) or like what do you mean by bad solution

Comment: You'll get solutions which are infinite series instead of polynomials, and non-integrable at infinity.

Comment: @IvanNeretin oh okay. Is there a textbook which talks about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer to your question. (a)  When solving a differential equation the boundary conditions *must* be specified (this is not always emphasised enough in textbooks), and (b) these conditions are determined by the physics of the problem via the postulates of quantum mechanics, including the nature of the wavefunction. Quantum mechanics (QM) has no derivation; we accept its postulates and QM survives only because experiment has so far always confirmed it.

As an example of quantisation consider the particle in a box. Here there are all sorts of solutions to the differential equation, i.e Schroedinger's equation. However, as the walls are infinitely high the wavefunction must have zero amplitude here and this means that the only solutions that remain and are physically realistic are when quantum number $n$ is quantised. The fact that the wavefunction must be zero at each wall are the boundary conditions.

A similar situation occurs on a particle on a ring where the angular momentum quantum number $l$ is quantised only because we insist, by applying the postulates of QM that the wavefunction repeats itself *exactly* each $2\pi$ round the circle. This is in effect the boundary condition.

In the H atom the equation is far more complicated but the general conditions imposed on the wavefunction remains the same; the imposition of boundary conditions, as determined by QM, results in the generation of integer quantum numbers so that theory matches experimental data.

Comment: you said by applying the postulates of QM that the wavefunction repeats itself exactly each 2π round the circle but isnt this the boundary condition for n like 2×pi×r=n lambda. Can you explain a bit more on how it extends to azimuthal quantum number and imposition of boundary conditions that force integer quantum numbers

Comment: The boundary condition on $\psi$ is that $\psi (0)=\psi(2\pi)$ *and* that the gradient $d\psi/d(\theta) $is the same at $0$ and $2\pi$